# Calling vendor scripts returns a blank page CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am running a cakePHP app that has to call external 1st party php scripts. Controller action flow looks like this:

```
function add($id = null, $year = null, $month = null, $day = null, $project_id = null){
...
    if($this->saveRepeatedEvents($event, $employees, $weekdays)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Events have been saved'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'index'));
    }
...
}

function saveRepeatedEvents($event, $employees, $weekdays) {
    App::import('Vendor', 'notifications/Notifications');

    $notifications = new Notifications;

    // code omitted…

    $notifications->send_notification($employees, $eventId, $numberOfEvents);

    return true;
}
```

The external scripts are called and they do what they are expected to do. The problem is that after the scripts are executed the app is supposed to set a flash and redirect a user, but all that happens is that a blank page is returned.

I have checked the error logs, but they ar empty as well.

I am really lost in this situation and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: “Blank page” is usually a sign of a fatal error. So enable sensible error_reporting and check your error log files.

Comment: Where should I enable the error_reporting? There is an initial CakePHP app and the "Notifications.php" has around 7 scripts called down the way. And I do not have access to php.ini on the server.

Comment: Check your error log at **app/tmp/logs/error.log** for the last fatal error thrown.

Comment: Blank page and blank error.log could mean another thing - someone exit the execution. Simply step into the vendor and see what they are doing?

Comment: @MartinBean, as I have stated in the question, there are no erros given.

Comment: @LionelChan, the vendor scripts are quite long to investigate it line by line. Is there any way to debug it quicker and more efficient?

Comment: @Domas In that case, you need to stop halting the execution of your script by putting `exit()` on a line and refreshing the page until it breaks; the line above will then be the problematic line and will give you a pointer as to what code to inspect. We can’t diagnose the problem if we have no error message to go on; all you’ve given us is some application code.

Comment: @Domas Actually, looking at your code, why is your `if` statement the same level as the `saveRepeatedEvents()` function? That `if` statement should be in a function itself.

Comment: @MartinBean, I wanted to omit code as much as possible, but have editted it now. the if statement is definately in a function.